# c++ tgamma() function has different outputs

Tags: c++, c++11

if you enter n=6, this code returns 719

```
int main()
    {
        long n,k;
        cin>>n;
        k = tgamma(n+1);
        cout<<k;
    }
```

while this code below will return correct answer 720

```
int main()
{
    long n,k;
    n=6;
    k = tgamma(n+1);
    cout<<k;
}
```

why is this happening?

I'm using [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/) for testing

Comment: Check this out: https://ideone.com/uEEG2y and https://ideone.com/hlR1zg. Both gets the same result

Comment: i was using http://cpp.sh/ for testing, seems like it works correctly on ideone

Comment: DO not use  cpp.sh for interactive input. It does not work properly.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Don't blame cpp.sh, I have used gcc on my machine and got 719 in both cases.

Comment: @n.m. It is a word of warning. It really does not always work. I answered many question on cplusplus.com about program skipping input, which is actually was a fault of this compiler interactive mode.

Comment: @MisterM - to be sure about the doubt of Revolver_Ocelot, could you, in both versions of the program, substitute `cout<<k;` with `cout<<k<<", "<<n;`?

Comment: The problem is not with cpp.sh, check out my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38019565/5617989).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**std::tgamma** according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/tgamma) **returns double** when it takes long. And, **double to long** conversions can be affected by precision loss.

This is what I got on disassembling the program. Looks like compiler has done a magic (technically known as Optimization).

The program in the left is the first one and the one in right is the second one.

[image: Program 1 vs. Program 2]

**Program 2 Line 33:** The compiler has already done the calculations to find the value of `tgamma(6 + 1)` as 720. The compiler actually applied the value and simplified the expression.

## What happens in Program 1?

**Program 2 Line 42:** [cvtsi2sdq]Assembly level instruction for *Convert Doubleword Integer to Scalar Double-Precision Floating-Point Value*

**Program 2 Line 44:** [cvttsd2siq] Assembly level instruction for *Convert Scalar Double-Precision Floating-Point Value to Signed Doubleword Integer with Truncation*

The second mentioned conversion is supposed to cause the type conversion precision loss resulting in the unexpected value 719 (truncated from, say, 719.9299328).

SPOILER: Simply use double in place long to avoid this error.